# angularJS ng-show blocking ng-click until double click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wai-aria

I have an input (code below) that has an ng-show that appears when you leave the field and it is invalid. However, I believe this is preventing my ng-click from happening on the next element. When I am focused in the first input and go to click the div with the `ng-click` it takes two clicks before the function is called.

I wanted to reach out because I wasn't sure if there was a way around this, if there was something else I could do to stop the ng-show from "blocking" my ng-click.

```
    <label for="input-idNumber" id="id-number">Enter your ID number</label>
    <input
    id="input-idNumber"
    ng-model="idNumber"
    name="idNumber"
    type="number"
    maxlength="10"
    required />

    <div class="desc-text">
      <p id="id-number-error"
          role="alert"
          class="text--error"
          ng-show="form.idNumber.$invalid && (form.$submitted || form.idNumber.$touched)">Enter a valid ID</p>
    </div>

<div class="question col-xs-12"
  ng-click="toggleDisplay()">
  <div
    id="find"
    class="inline-block"
    tabindex="0"
    role="button">
    <p class="q-text">
      <strong>How do I find my ID?</strong>
    </p>
  </div>
```

**toggleDisplay() function**

```
$scope.toggleDisplay = function() {
    var child = document.querySelector( ".question-content" );
    var hidden = child.getAttribute("aria-hidden");
    var expanded = child.getAttribute("aria-expanded");
    hidden === "true" ? hidden = false : hidden = true;
    expanded === "true" ? expanded = false : expanded = true;
    child.setAttribute("aria-hidden", hidden);
    child.setAttribute("aria-expanded", expanded);
};
```

Comment: What does `toggleDisplay()` do?

Comment: ah, sorry @Brian I probably should have included that it hides/shows the other content in the div. shown below

```$scope.toggleDisplay = function() {

      var child = document.querySelector( ".question-content" );
      var hidden = child.getAttribute("aria-hidden");
      var expanded = child.getAttribute("aria-expanded");

      hidden === "true" ? hidden = false : hidden = true;
      expanded === "true" ? expanded = false : expanded = true;

      child.setAttribute("aria-hidden", hidden);
      child.setAttribute("aria-expanded", expanded);
    };```

Comment: Thank you - I added it into your main question for others to find / view easier.

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, DOM manipulation should not be done in controllers. DOM manipulation should be done with directives. Controllers manipulates the Model and directives manipulate the DOM based on the state of the Model.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [ngAria](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAria) to handle `aria-hidden`. For `aria-expanded`, we'll have to use interpolation. My solution removes the requirement for the `toggleDisplay()` function in your controller.

**Toggling the display**
For this, I would use this shorthand, which basically sets `displayToggle` to what it is not (toggle it).

```
<div class="question col-xs-12"
     ng-click="displayToggle =! displayToggle">
```

**question-content div**

```
<div class="question-content"
     aria-expanded="{{displayToggle}}"
     ng-show="displayToggle">
        You can find it by..
</div>
```

**To use ng-aria**

1. Include in your HTML: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular-aria.js"></script>`
2. Include in your module dependencies: `angular.module('moduleName', ['ngAria']);`

**Why not just use `aria-hidden="{{displayToggle}}"`?**
You certainly can, and avoid the extra dependency. It is good to know about though, and if you review [their documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAria), you'll find it can be quite useful in that their other directives will pull it in. I am surprised that `aria-expanded` is not included there.

Answer (score 0):

old question, but if anyone comes across this

this is because when the element appears via ng-show, the div below it moves and it turns out that the 'click' didn't hit it. Try adding a space so that when you display the element via ng-show it doesn't move the "div with ng-click" underneath it.